# What is the purpose of GeometryCollection Option Associated with the Shape Dropdown?

Tags: geoserver

I have some data sets that have point, line and polygons in the same table and I have been selecting the Type "GeometryCollection" for the shape column.  I have noticed that items such as labels do not behave consistently when I make this selection.  What is the purpose of this option and is there a better way to handle multiple Shape types?

Comment: how can a generic geometry collection behave consistently? it contains random geometries

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: probably duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240709/geoserver-layer-styling-with-multiple-geometries